# Переберите этот объект циклом и запишите в новый объект те элементы, которые являются четными числами. Не пойму как это сделать

Tags: javascript

```
let obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5};
let obj2 = {};

for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    if (obj1 % 2 === 0) {
        obj2 = obj1[key];
    }
}
console.log(obj1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так:

```js
let obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5};
let obj2 = {};

for (let i in obj1) {
if (obj1[i] % 2 === 0) {
    obj2[i] = obj1[i];
}
}
console.log(obj2);
```

Comment: Спасибо принцип понял.